# How do I add Sublime Text 2 keybindings?

Tags: macos, sublimetext

I am looking to get the following assigned to Keybindings. I am able to make a snippet for this, yet would prefer to be able to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd> just like in Textmate.

```
<%= %>
```

What do I need to add and where do I need to add it, or where could I find out.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you just want to literally insert those characters, you can set up your "User Key Bindings" like this:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+."], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "<%= %>"} }
]
```

You can use the Default Key Bindings file as an example for possible key binding commands. Both User and Default are located in Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences on OS X.

Not sure if you really wanted `"ctrl+shift+."`, but it would work as well.

To move the cursor to the middle during insert, you can use insert_snippet like this:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+."], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "<%=$0 %>"} }
]
```

Comment: Great shout - Thank you. Any idea how to get the cursor to be placed in the center of the tags for continued typing?

Comment: @lunixbochs Is there a way to set this up so that If I press the sequence again, it would remove the = ?

Comment: you can play with context - look at the default key bindings. I believe you can match regex before and after a section, so you could say "if my cursor is on =, with a <% and %> on either side, remove the ="

Comment: is the following the old way?  http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/plugin-examples   <binding key="ctrl+alt+d" command="duplicate"/>  ?

Comment: Yep. The Sublime Text 3 documentation lives at http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/

Answer (score 3):

Just found this, thought it might be helpful: https://github.com/eddorre/SublimeERB