# sublime text 2 ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext

I've been watching some Railscast episodes and it looks like he's using Sublime Text as his editor. How does he create new <% %> tags? I can tell he's using a shortcut but can't figure out what it is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: nice & keen observation of the railscasts, I would also like to know as I always manually type it :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add Sublime Text 2 keybindings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635417/how-do-i-add-sublime-text-2-keybindings)

Comment: From what I know, Ryan bates uses textmate with bundles to auto write tags

Comment: link posted by jsumners solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know what the "<% %> tags" are, but I imagine the presenter is using the [ERB Insert and Toggle Commands](https://github.com/eddorre/SublimeERB) add-on. The animated GIF on the project's description page shows such things being used.

Comment: this works great, and as Justin mentioned he's using Textmate not Sublime but this works for me!